# How to handle jmeter for a Website which has form made in JavaScript which does a post back on next and previous

Tags: javascript, jmeter

I have to make a load test script for a website's registration and payment. The registration has a few steps like email then click on next button order info comes and then next brings up contact info and after that payment. This email, order, contact info and payment all are in JavaScript and clicking on next button performs a postback.

How do I handle this with JMeter? I recorded the above scenario with JMeter2.10 using the test script recorder.  It recorded all the requests with parameters. But when I run these requests I can see in response that values were sent in request but are not submitted in the form.

How should I be able to create this load test script which has the whole registration in JavaScript?

Comment: @E.S: It's great that you're trying to improve other people's post, but make sure you're using the right tool for the right task. Code spans (which look `like this`) should only be used to emphasise code or language keywords within a sentence. For example, using code spans for something like "_Where should I use `<pre>`?_" is fine, but don't use it for stuff like language names (e.g. `JavaScript`) or to emphasise words (use bold and/or italic instead). Thanks!

Comment: Thanks guys for making my post more readable. But I'll appreciate if you can also help with the resolution. Thanks

Comment: @CharanSethi: sorry, I'm not familiar with JMeter, but hopefully someone is :)

Answer (score 1):

Parameters, you're recorded can be dynamic. You need to implement something called `correlation` - the process of extracting dynamic values from response and adding them to next request.

The most commonly used JMeter components are

- [Regular Expressions Extractor](http://blazemeter.com/blog/using-regular-expressions-jmeter)
- [XPath Extractor](http://blazemeter.com/blog/using-xpath-extractor-jmeter-0)

So consider following steps:

1. Record your test case several times using [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.pdf)
2. Detect which parameters being sent are dynamic
3. Inspect pages source code (use [View Results Tree](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener for this. By the way, in JMeter 2.11 it's capable of evaluating XPath right in the listener).
4. Extract necessary values and save them to JMeter Variables
5. Substitute recorded hard-coded values with relevant variables

That's it.

Above links to post-processors contain several useful examples. If you'll be still experiencing problems - update your question with server response details and either myself or community will help you to generate appropriate regular or xpath expression.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply. I want to know how can we handle javascript with jmeter. If there are several details for which javascript is used, How should i create that request for jmeter as jmeter runs at protocol level and hence if the details are being submitted to the databse with javascript , How do i test the registeration using jmeter.

Comment: JMeter itself isn't capable of executing javascript. But if javascript triggers some XMLHttpRequest(s) which is/are being asynchronously executed from browser - these requests can be simulated with JMeter.

Comment: Thanks Dmitri. Would u pls help me as how can i create a jmeter script for website registration page in aspx in which after adding details the next button performs a js postback to the same page and new fields are dynamically generated until all fields required for registration have been provided input from user. How do i handle this. when i record this with test script recorder jmeter makes several HTTP requests and shows js parameters with them. When i run this View results tree doesn't show any errors but i'm not sure whether jmeter is able to submit the values in the registration form

Comment: If there is a query to server - JMeter Proxy will record it alternatively you can use [Google Chrome Plugin](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/blazemeter-the-load-testi/mbopgmdnpcbohhpnfglgohlbhfongabi?hl=en_). If new input fields become visible without sending anything to server - you don't need to care about it as nobody is testing performance of client-side javascript